What do these equations, (1)-(3) , associated with problem 4.137 of Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$ actually mean?
Problem 4.137  of Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$ is quoted below ( a slightly corrected version of ).

Let $t_1$,$t_2$,$\cdots$,$t_n$ be symbols, and let $K$ be any field.
Let $V$ be the following set of expressions where $a_i \in K:$
\begin{equation*}
     a_1t_1+ a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n \end{equation*}
Define addition in $V$ and scalar multiplication on $V$ by
\begin{align*}    ( a_1t_1+ \cdots+a_nt_n ) + ( b_1t_1+ \cdots+b_nt_n
 ) &=  ( a_1 +b_1)t_1+ \cdots+(a_n+b_n)t_n    \\ k( a_1t_1+
a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n  )&=ka_1t_1+ka_2t_2+\cdots+ka_nt_n \end{align*}
Show that $V$ is a vector space over $K$ with the above operations.
Also, show that ${t_1,\cdots,t_n}$ is a basis of $V$,
where
\begin{equation*} t_j=0t_1+\cdots+0t_{j-1}+1t_j+ 0t_{j+1}+\cdots+0t_n
 \end{equation*}

Writing out some of the $t_j$ definitions, we have
\begin{align*}
 t_1&=1t_1+0t_2+\cdots+0t_n  \tag{1}  \\
  t_2&=0t_1+1t_2+\cdots+0t_n  \tag{2}    \\
  &\vdots \\
 t_n&=0t_1+0t_2+\cdots+1t_n  \tag{3}  
\end{align*}
My question is: What do these equations,  (1)-(3) , associated with problem 4.137 of Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$ actually mean?
Other Information
Related Question
Are sets of symbols, specified as in problem 4.137 of Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$, collections of linearly independent elements?
Reference.
1, Seymour Lipschutz, PhD, Marc Lipson, PhD, SCHAUM’s outlines, Linear Algebra, Fourth Edition, McGraw Hill (2009).

Considering how scalar multiplication is defined, wouldn't each symbol be a scaling of the standard basis of said vector space?

They are the canonical basis vectors over a vector space. If they were tuples with $n=3$ you'd have $t_1=(1,0,0),t_2=(0,1,0)$ and $t_3=(0,0,1)$ where each tuple is the symbol. I think they want to get you used to the additive notation with symbols so that they can generalize to different bases more readily.

The understanding, that allowed me to put together this answer, was gained from ‘ConMan’, see at
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4958625/553318
In problem 4.137, the vector space $V$ is composed of expressions of the form
\begin{equation*}
a_1t_1+ a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n 
\end{equation*}
Note that these expressions, always contain every one of the symbols {$t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n$}.
An individual symbol, say ‘$t_j$’, is not an expression of the form that belongs in $V$.
However, by writing
\begin{equation*} 
t_j=0t_1+\cdots+0t_{j-1}+1t_j+ 0t_{j+1}+\cdots+0t_n
\end{equation*}
we can still consider ‘$t_j$’ to be an element of $V$.
cf ConMan says

and we can write $\blacksquare = 1 \blacksquare + 0 \bigtriangleup$
and $\bigtriangleup = 0 \blacksquare + 1 \bigtriangleup$, noting that
we are still treating these as vectors within the vector space.

